# How to determine the center and radius of a circle in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

I know, this question is all over the place but hear me out please. I'm asking for a simple way to find the center and radius (simple meaning without assuming that cross-ratio of $z_1, z_2, z_3, z$ must be real or any other knowledge of actual complex analysis). At the same time solving the system of three equations sounds like unnecessarily daunting of a challenge. I've tried searching all over the Internet but no luck so far. And yes, turning the problem into a bunch of real and imaginary components is not 'nice', I expect the formulae to be in pure $z_1, z_2, z_3, z$ if at all possible. Appreciate the help :)

EDIT: circle should contain $z_1, z_2, z_3$ which are not on the same line

Comment: I guess you mean the circle goes through $z_1,\ z_2,\ z_3.$ Is that right? [You don't actually say so in your question.]

Comment: @coffeemath yes, I edited that in

Comment: A *nice* solution can be found by treating the three points on the circle as a triangle. Then you have only to find the circumcenter of that triangle to solve your problem. There are well-known algorithms for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer: this answer is only geometric and not complex-algebraic. If one carries out the final steps I describe, perhaps there's some nice complex algebra that can be extracted.

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be non-colinear and lie on a circle of centre $c$ and radius $r$. Set $s_i = z_i-z_1$ for $i = 1,2,3$ and $C = z_1-c$. We first express $C$ in terms of $s_2,s_3$. By assumption $s_2,s_3$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent. Thus, we can write
\begin{equation*}
C = a_2 s_2 + a_3s_3
\end{equation*}
for some unique $a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$. Make use of the scalar product $\langle x,y \rangle = \text{Re}(x \overline{y})$. Let $i \in \{2,3\}$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\|z_i-c\| = r.
\end{equation*}
Moreover,
\begin{equation*}
z_i-c = (z_i-z_1)+(z_1 - c) = s_i + C. 
\end{equation*}
So, because $\|C\|^2 = \|z_1-c\|^2 = r^2$, we have
\begin{equation*}
r^2 = \|z_i-c\|^2 = \|s_i + C\|^2 = \|s_i\|^2 + 2 \langle s_i,C\rangle + \|C\|^2 = \|s_i\|^2 + 2 \langle s_i,C\rangle + r^2.
\end{equation*}
That is
\begin{equation*}
\langle s_i,C\rangle = -\frac{1}{2}\|s_i\|^2.
\end{equation*}
Moreover,
\begin{equation*}
\langle s_i,C\rangle = \langle s_i,a_2 s_2 + a_3 s_3\rangle = a_2 \langle s_i,s_2\rangle + a_3 \langle s_i,s_3\rangle. 
\end{equation*}
Thus, we have that
\begin{equation*}
a_2 \langle s_i,s_2\rangle + a_3 \langle s_i,s_3\rangle = -\frac{1}{2}\|s_i\|^2.
\end{equation*}
That is, $(a_2,a_3)$ solves the system
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle s_2, s_2 \rangle & \langle s_2, s_3 \rangle\\
\langle s_3, s_2 \rangle & \langle s_3, s_3 \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2\\
a_3
\end{pmatrix}
 = 
-\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\|s_2\|^2\\
\|s_3\|^2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Since $s_2,s_3$ are linearly independent, it follows that the columns of this matrix are linearly independent as well. One has a simple formula for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix. We thus have determined $a_2,a_3$ and thus $C$. To determine the centre, we note that $c = z_1 - C$. We also determine the radius from $r = \|C\|$.

Comment: It seems like there's no 'nice' solution. I expanded everything out and it turned into a giant formula with almost nothing to cancel out. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! The matrix on the right hand side is the matrix rep of the inner product in the basis $(s_2, s_3)$. So it's determinant will be the determinant of the matrix $(s_2 ~ s_3)$ which is the imaginary part of $s_2 s_3$. This might help.